Need help in right-shifting a task in production schedule of multiple machines and multiple jobs
I am developing a flexible job shop scheduling algorithm with fuzzy processing times, where I try to defuzzyify the production times as times progress.
This is one of the crisp schedules I generated. However, I find that as I defuzziify production schedules, I have job wise overlap, meaning an operation is getting started before its preceding operation. However, I've ensured that machine wise dependencies are sorted out well. The code to view this issue is as follows:
import copy
import numpy as np

# Machine dictionary with [job, machine, start, end, 0, 2] format
machine_dict = {1: [[1, 3, [120.46, 153.93, 174.0], [140.22, 179.17, 202.54], 0, 2], [2, 2, [348.02, 444.69, 502.69], [409.87, 523.72, 592.03], 0, 2]], 2: [[4, 3, [140.66, 179.74, 203.18], [159.86, 204.28, 230.92], 0, 2], [2, 4, [418.38, 534.6, 604.33], [474.35, 606.11, 685.17], 0, 2]], 3: [[2, 1, [0, 0, 0], [348.02, 444.69, 502.69], 0, 2]], 4: [[3, 2, [17.362573615775315, 17.362573615775315, 17.362573615775315], [52.10257361577531, 61.75257361577532, 67.54257361577531], 0, 2], [3, 3, [312.64, 399.47, 451.58], [579.64, 740.6300000000001, 837.24], 0, 2]], 5: [[4, 1, [0, 0, 0], [89.23, 114.02, 128.89], 0, 2]], 6: [[5, 1, [0, 0, 0], [84.93, 108.53, 122.68], 0, 2], [5, 2, [134.72, 172.15, 194.6], [184.51, 235.77, 266.52], 0, 2]], 7: [[1, 1, [0, 0, 0], [49.65, 63.45, 71.72], 0, 2], [1, 2, [120.46, 153.93, 174.0], [191.26999999999998, 244.41000000000003, 276.28], 0, 2]], 8: [[4, 5, [183.09, 233.97, 264.48], [216.45, 276.59, 312.66], 0, 2]], 10: [[4, 4, [159.86, 204.28, 230.92], [183.09, 233.97, 264.48], 0, 2]], 11: [[3, 1, [0, 0, 0], [11.0, 11.0, 11.0], 0, 2], [4, 2, [192.08999999999997, 245.46000000000004, 277.47], [243.51999999999995, 311.18000000000006, 351.76000000000005], 0, 2], [2, 3, [426.89, 545.48, 616.6300000000001], [435.4, 556.36, 628.9300000000002], 0, 2]]}





# Function to print job-wise operation details with machine, start and end times
def print_job_operations(machine_dict):
    job_operations = {}
  
    # Organize operations by job
    for machine, operations in machine_dict.items():
        for op in operations:
            job_id, op_id, start_times, end_times, *_ = op
            if job_id not in job_operations:
                job_operations[job_id] = []
            job_operations[job_id].append((op_id, machine, start_times, end_times))  # Store operation ID, machine, start/end times
    
    # Now print the job-wise operations with machine, start and end times
    for job_id, ops in job_operations.items():
        print(f"Job {job_id}:")
        for op in sorted(ops, key=lambda x: x[0]):  # Sort by operation number
            print(f"  Operation {op[0]} - Machine: {op[1]}, Start Time: {op[2]}, End Time: {op[3]}")
       


# Function to get end time of last operation of each job
def get_last_operation_end_times(machine_dict):
    job_operations = {}
  
    # Organize operations by job
    for machine, operations in machine_dict.items():
        for op in operations:
            job_id, op_id, start_times, end_times, *_ = op
            if job_id not in job_operations:
                job_operations[job_id] = []
            job_operations[job_id].append((op_id, end_times))  # Store operation ID and end times
    
    # Get the end time of the last operation for each job
    last_operation_end_times = {}
    for job_id, ops in job_operations.items():
        last_op = max(ops, key=lambda x: x[0])  # Get the operation with the highest operation number
        last_operation_end_times[job_id] = last_op[1]  # Store the end times of the last operation
    
    return last_operation_end_times


# Printing the adjusted machine-wise and job-wise schedule
print_job_operations(machine_dict)

# Getting the end time of the last operation of each job
last_op_end_times = get_last_operation_end_times(machine_dict)
last_op_end_times

My code to fix this issue is as follows:
for machine, ops in machine_dict.items():
    #Sort operations by start time (Use middle TFN value for sorting)
    ops = sorted(ops, key=lambda x: x[2][1])
    for op in ops:
        job, opn, start, end, _, _ = op
        if (opn>1):
           job_prev_end=job_operations[job,opn-1][3]
        else:
            job_prev_end=[0,0,0]
        machine_prev_end= machine_end_times[machine]
        print(machine)
        print("op-start",start,"op-end",end,"machine_prev_end",machine_prev_end,"job_prev_end",job_prev_end)
       # Calculate the adjusted start time based on the latest end time
        adjusted_start = [max(start[i], machine_prev_end[i], job_prev_end[i]) for i in range(3)]
        duration = [end[i] - start[i] for i in range(3)]
        adjusted_end = [adjusted_start[i] + duration[i] for i in range(3)]
        # Store the adjusted operation in the final schedule
        print([job, opn, adjusted_start, adjusted_end, 0, 2])
        # Update end times for job and machine
        job_end_times[job] = adjusted_end
        machine_end_times[machine] = adjusted_end
        if(job==4):
           input()
        adjusted_schedule[machine].append([job, opn, adjusted_start, adjusted_end, 0, 2])


However, I find that this code does not solve the issue as it takes job-operation pairs in the order that they are scheduled in machines (starting from machine 1)- meaning if operation 4 of job 4 is scheduled on machine 3 and operation 4-3 is scheduled on machine 10 and if operation 4 of job 4 begins before operation 4-3, this overlap is not rectified.
How can I right shift jobs/operations to avoid overlap in a production schedule?
